# change color of opacity using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of the opacity. I have the following:

```
img{  
    background-color:red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

So the color of the opacity will be red but it's white. How can I change the color because this doesn't work!

Comment: Worked for me with **Chrome 32** http://jsbin.com/runexedu/1/edit Also tested with **FF 9.0.1+** and **IE8+**

Comment: Have you tried to add `background-color: red` to the `.imagini:hover`?

Comment: I don't want on hover to be red..

Answer (score 3):

Use [rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/):

```
.imagini{
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.imagini:hover{
    background:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the reason OP didn't do this in the first place is for compatbility - hence archaic `filter:alpha` usage.

Comment: this doesn't do anything for my image...

Comment: So you are applying this to an image? You should edit your post to note this, as is an important matter.

Comment: Also if you wish compability you may use an SVG background
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.5" ></rect></svg>

Answer (score 0):

When playing with opacity and background color it also depends what background your container is.
When reducing opacity with 50% this already can be too much and have contrast issues with the background color (ie white) of the body or content container. Also why not put the hover effect on a wrapping element of the image. That way you have more styling freedom. And you can isolate it from the image. Also I advice against using opacity all together and use rgba() as the preferred method.